# Standard equation for delivered power from synchronous generator wrong for fractional kW machines?

Tags: power, low-power, generator, electric-machine, synchronous

When synchronous machines get to a certain size (in the \$MW\hspace{-0.8mm}s\$) the armature resistance is a lot smaller than the synchronous reactance, \$R_A << X_s\$, because of this \$R_A\$ is ignored when deriving the formula for the active power \$P\$ being delivered by a synchronous generator. Thus when \$R_A\$ is ignored the phasor diagram of a synchronous generator with lagging \$p\hspace{-0.5mm}f\$ is simplified to:
[image: Phasor diagram - Synchronous generator, lagging pf]

From \$P=V_\phi I_A\, cos(\theta)\$ and the phasor diagram above \$P\$ for \$MW\$ machines is usually derived to be \$P_{MW\,sized\,machine} \approx \dfrac{V_\phi E_A}{X_s}\,sin(\delta)\$.

For fractional \$kW\$ machines however; \$R_A\$ and \$X_s\$ can be much closer to equalling one another than the relationship found for much larger machines. A fractional \$kW\$ machine I am looking at has \$R_A(T_0) = 0.69 \,\Omega\$ and \$X_s(\omega_0) = 1.08 \, \Omega\$, \$R_A\$ should in my mind therefore clearly not be neglected when calculating \$P\$ for a fractional \$kW\$ machine!

Because of this I tried to derive the equations for \$P\$ without setting \$R_A = 0\, \Omega\$, yet agian using \$P=V_\phi I_A\, cos(\theta)\$, but unlike before it is being combined with the three following phasor diagrams in mind (where \$R_A \neq 0 \, \Omega\$):

[image: Phasor diagrams for synchronous generators]

\$(a)\$ For unity \$p\hspace{-0.5mm}f\$: \$P_{kW\,sized\,machine} = \dfrac{V_\phi}{X_s}E_A\,sin(\delta)\$

\$(b)\$ For lagging \$p\hspace{-0.5mm}f\$: \$P_{kW\,sized\,machine} = \dfrac{V_\phi}{X_s}[E_A\,sin(\delta)+I_A R_A\,sin(\theta)] \$

\$(c)\$ For leading \$p\hspace{-0.5mm}f\$: \$P_{kW\,sized\,machine} = \dfrac{V_\phi}{X_s}[E_A\,sin(\delta)-I_A R_A\, sin(\theta)]\$

Are the equations presented in \$(a), (b)\$ and \$(c)\$ correct, and if not, what are the correct equations?

Comment: "armature resistance is larger"? or is it smaller? Please edit your question further.

Comment: For MW sized alternators armature resistance is neglected. I, however don't like this assumption for fractional kW machines as the size of the armature resistance isn't that different from the synchronous reactance, as stated in the numerical example given above. Will edit to clearify further.

Comment: \$R_A << X_s\$ means that \$R_A\$ is much smaller than \$X_s\$ , but the first sentence says, it is much larger? Later on you say these quantities "can be much closer to equalling each other" and use the same inequality.

Comment: The sentence should say *much smaller* offcourse! ty

Comment: Check this [book](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=oiwN1mjMKMkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 408-411 for solved examples on how to add vectors for various power factors.